# What all can be done in Preferences.tps file apart from regular,sequential and Divergent Color-palette?

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to create a generic styling (branding) across the workbooks. So i thought of creating custom-color-palette in Preferences.tps. Can someone guide me what else can be achieved using this file? Any leads are highly appreciated.